# How do I reserve disk space in MS SQL script?

Tags: sql

I was asked to create an MS SQL script that will create a database and reserve a 50 MB free disk space? How can I do that and what are the commands to use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following is what you are looking for.

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB 
    ON
    (
        FILENAME = 'c:\myDB.mdf',
        SIZE = 50MB,
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
        FILEGROWTH = 5MB
    )
LOG 
ON
    ( 
        NAME = 'TestDB_log',
        FILENAME = 'c:\myDB.ldf',
        SIZE = 1MB,
        MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED,
        FILEGROWTH = 5MB 
    )
```

Also look at the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer.